# AWS offerings + Kubernetes - is there some cross over?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

So I am reading about `kubernetes` and `AWS` service offerings. For example, one of the main advantages of kubernetes is load balancing but AWS [has this too](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

How do all these products tie in with one another? Are lots of them doing the same job? Is it just a case that there are so many tools out there now?

Maybe this isn't the correct forum for this question. If not I can remove, but just feel a bit overwhelmed with all the various options, and wondering if they are all completely different.

Comment: It depend on what you are going to achieve. What is your task or project?

Answer (score 3):

AWS offers much more services than load balancing, automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications, which Kubernetes is.

If you mean [Amazon EC2 Container Service (ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), so both of them fast and scalable solutions for container management.

Actually, there is an managed [Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) also, which integrated with other AWS infrastructure, such as security, monitoring, etc.

So, it depends on your needs. You can read [compare of AWS ECS and Kubernetes](https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/kubernetes/ec2-container-service-vs-kubernetes).

**UPDATE**
[Here is](https://atodorov.me/2020/06/14/comparing-kubernetes-managed-services-across-digital-ocean-scaleway-ovhcloud-and-linode/) a big comparison of managed Kubernetes services across Digital Ocean, Scaleway, OVHCloud and Linode.

Answer (score 3):

**Kubernetes** is an infrasructure-agnostic framework for orchestrating containers. It can run on your laptop (Minikube), or installed on a couple of EC2 instances in AWS, or in a fully-managed offering from GCP, Azure and other cloud providers. Many users and organizations choose Kubernetes because of this portability.

**AWS**, OTOH, is a global cloud provider,or hyperscaler, with over 200 different services. It is impossible to cover them all.  Nevertheless, if we narrow it to container-centric services: AWS offers its own proprietary orchestration tools: **ECS** and **Fargate**.

[image]

Comment: Where did that image come from? It's misleading because you can't use Fargate by itself, you use Fargate with either EKS or ECS.